# Latex \item{} help required

Tags: lists

I am writing a IEEETran paper in Latex and encountering following error. My code snippet is as under

```
\begin{description}
  \item[\textbf{1. Business}], how to make profit from your products.
  \item[\textbf{2. Architecture}], technical means to build the software.
  \item[\textbf{3. Process}], roles, responsibilities, and relationships within software   development.
  \item[\textbf{4. Organization}], actual mapping of roles and responsibilities to organizational structures.
   \end{description}
```

what I actually get is something like this 
[image]

what I am actually looking for should be

[image]

any help should be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [enumerate](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Enumerate):

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{Business}, how to make profit from your products.
\item \textbf{Architecture}, technical means to build the software.
\item \textbf{Process}, roles, responsibilities, and relationships within software development.
\item \textbf{Organization}, actual mapping of roles and responsibilities to organizational structures.
\end{enumerate}
```